# How to find recall and precision between query image and retrieved images?

Tags: python, precision, confusion-matrix

I have developed image retrieval system using deep learning and flask. I upload input image and system will give me similar images according to query image as well indices of that images and distances between query image and retrieved image. now I want to find precision and recall of resulted image. How I can do it?